# Validar un DNI - NIF en PHP

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

continuando con el registro de clientes, tengo que validar si el el DNI o NIF existe, además me gustaria saber si se puede comprobar si el DNI o NIF es correcto. También me gustaria el hecho es que en el input pusiera una mascara con los campos que tienen que haber y no se salgan de ahí. Muestro lo que tengo ahora:

`input del dni nif`

```
<div class="col-5">
  <label class="inputReg">NIF/DNI</label>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 28px;">
     <input type="text" class=" my-form-control" id="nif" name="nif" placeholder="nif/dni" required />
    </div>
</div>
```

Aquí el `AJAX`

```
<script>
      $(function(){
          $("#formuploadajax1").on("submit", function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var f = $(this);
              var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formuploadajax1"));
              formData.append("dato", "valor");
              //formData.append(f.attr("name"), $(this)[0].files[0]);
              $.ajax({
                  url: "incluCuenta/insertar-cliente.php",
                  type: "post",
                  dataType: "html",
                  data: formData,
                  cache: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false
              })
                  .done(function(res){
                    if(res=="1"){
                        toastr["info"]("Registro exitoso!", "Mensaje")
                             setTimeout(function () {
                             window.location.href = "login.php"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
                         }, 1500); //will call the function after 2 secs
                    }else{
                        $("#mensaje").html(res);
                        toastr["error"]("Utiliza otro usuario!", "Mensaje")
                    }
                  });
          });
      });
    </script>
```

Aquí el `insertar-cliente.php`

```
<?php
    include "../conexion/conexion.php";

    mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");
    $results = 'SELECT * FROM Usuarios';
    $rec = mysqli_query($mysqli, $results);

    if ($rec === false) {
    die('ERROR SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($mysqli)));
    }
    while ($results = mysqli_fetch_object($rec)) {

    if(mb_strtolower($results->Username) == mb_strtolower($_POST['email'])) {

    die('<div class=\'form\'> 
        <div class="alert alert-danger" style="font-size: 14px;"><strong>¡Error!</strong> Este usuario ya esta en uso.</div>

    </div>');
    }
 }

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']);
$telefono = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['telefono']);
$movil = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['movil']);
$nif = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['nif']);
$direccion = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['direccion']);
$postal = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['postal']);
$poblacion = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['poblacion']);
$provincia = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['provincia']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['pass']);
$sexo = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['sexo']);

$fecha = date('y,m,d');

$results = "
 INSERT INTO Usuarios (
    Fecha,
    Sexo,
    Nombre,
    Password,
    Username,
    Direccion,
    Postal,
    Poblacion,
    Provincia,
    Telefono,
    Movil,
    Dni,
    intestado
 ) VALUES (
    '$fecha',
    '$sexo',
    '$name',
    '$pass',
    '$email',
    '$direccion',
    '$postal',
    '$poblacion',
    '$provincia',
    '$telefono',
    '$movil',
    '$nif',
    '1'
 )
";
if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $results) === false) {
/* Aquí olvidaste poner como primer parámetro la conexión mysqli */
die('Error SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($mysqli)));
}

echo "1";
```

Comment: Si solo validas el nif, puedes poner una máscara pero si tambien admites cif, ten en cuenta que no lleva letra detrás sino delante, así que mejor que valides si es correcto o no en lugar de poner una máscara. Aquí tienes un par de ejemplos para validarlo: https://github.com/amnesty/drupal-nif-nie-cif-validator/blob/master/includes/nif-nie-cif.php y https://bulma.net/funcion-para-validar-el-nif-cif-y-nie-en-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comprobar si el DNI está repetido puedes agregar la comprobación en el bucle `while`:

```
<?php
/* ... */
while ($results = mysqli_fetch_object($rec)) {
    if (mb_strtolower($results->Username) == mb_strtolower($_POST['email'])) {
        die('<div class=\'form\'> 
        <div class="alert alert-danger" style="font-size: 14px;"><strong>¡Error!</strong> Este usuario ya esta en uso.</div>
    </div>');
    }
    if (mb_strtolower($results->Dni) == mb_strtolower($_POST['nif'])) {
        die('<div class=\'form\'> 
        <div class="alert alert-danger" style="font-size: 14px;"><strong>¡Error!</strong> Este DNI ya está en uso.</div>
    </div>');
    }
}
```

Pero te recomiendo comprobar previamente que su formato es correcto tanto en Javascript como en PHP:

**Javascript**

```
function comprobar_nif(dni) {
    if (dni.length != 9) {
        return false;
    }
    /* Ajustamos las letras especiales "x", "y" y "z" */
    switch(dni.charAt(0).toLowerCase()) {
        case 'x':
            dni = '0' + dni.substr(1);
            break;
        case 'y':
            dni = '1' + dni.substr(1);
            break;
        case 'z':
            dni = '2' + dni.substr(1);
            break;
        }
    numero = parseInt(dni.substr(0, dni.length - 1)) % 23;
    letra = dni.substr(dni.length - 1, 1);
    return letra != 'TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET'.substring(numero, numero + 1);
}
```

Agregando la comprobación:

```
$("#formuploadajax1").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (comprobar_nif($('#nif').val()) == false) {
        alert('El DNI está mal');
        return;
    }
    /* ... */
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
function comprobar_nif($dni) {
    if (strlen($dni) != 9) {
        return false;
    }
    /* Ajustamos las letras especiales "x", "y" y "z" */
    switch(strtolower(substr($dni, 0, 1))) {
        case 'x':
            $dni = '0' + substr($dni, 1);
            break;
        case 'y':
            $dni = '1' + substr($dni, 1);
            break;
        case 'z':
            $dni = '2' + substr($dni, 1);
            break;
        }
    $numero = intval(substr($dni, 0, strlen($dni) - 1)) % 23;
    $letra = substr($dni, strlen($dni) - 1);
    return $letra == substr('TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET', $numero, 1);
}
/* Comprobamos si el DNI enviado por el formulario es válido */
if (comprobar_nif($_POST['nif']) === false) {
    die('<div class=\'form\'> 
    <div class="alert alert-danger" style="font-size: 14px;"><strong>¡Error!</strong> Este DNI no es válido.</div>
</div>');
}
```

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia, como puedo hacer funcionar esa función! gracias por elaporte del php ya lo tengo puesto

Comment: Un momento implemento la función en PHP e integro este código en tu javascript.

Comment: 1 puntualización. En JS se esta llamando a una funcion `comprobar_dni`cuando se llama `comprobar_nif`. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @JDev , estoy comiendo, así que las últimas modificaciones las hice desde el móvil. Ahora lo corrijo.

Comment: Te informo que con esto estas restringiendo a tus usuarios a que tengan un dni español. Ten en cuenta que si llega alguien con dni extranjero, la codificacion es completamente distinta. Esto te puede dar problemas mas adelante si se os ocurre internacionalizar la aplicacion.

Comment: Pero no es valido para un dni extranjero. El NIF es de España. Si yo fuera francés, tendría mi propio DNI de Francia. En ese caso, yo no podría utilizar la aplicación, porque mi DNI (francés) no es valido. Por eso aviso que luego si internacionaliza la aplicación, va a tener problemas, puesto que las validaciones de este tipo DEPENDEN del país y del algoritmo correspondiente..

Comment: Gracias por comentar y avisar, @Jakala . Aunque la variable se llame "dni" en realidad es un NIF para personas físicas, que comprenden los DNI y los NIE, por lo que también es válido para un extranjero residente en España. Entiendo perfectamente lo que quieres explicarme, pero no está en mi mano corregir eso. Esta es una respuesta a las necesidades de quien plantea la pregunta. Estas mejoras deberías plantearlas como comentario a la pregunta, para informar a la persona que pregunta que su aplicación no valdrán en otros países, no a mi respuesta. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: opss! sorry, pensaba que estaba comentando en la pregunta. Mil perdones!!! :)